# Triple Head 2 Go Digital Se

Tags: multiple-monitors, osx-mountain-lion, vga, dvi, mini-displayport

I am trying to connect my TripleHead2Go Digital SE, to 3 VGA monitors, It is unclear if they are incompatible since I had to get VGA to DVI converters. I am not sure if it just doesn't work with VGA monitors or if it's a software issue. but, its not working the Mac Maxtor software detects the monitors but does not display a thing, I have even tried it on the lowest resolution possible and it still does not give.

Answer (score 0):

The [specification page](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/th2go/digital_se/) of a TripleHead2Go Digital SE contains the following:

3 x [DVI-D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface) outputs

That is DVI-**D**, which means it is digital only.
VGA is analog.

[image]

This means you can not get this configuration to work without [an active DVI-D to analog convertor](http://uk.startech.com/AV/Converters/Video/DVI-D-to-VGA-Active-Adapter-Converter-Cable-1920x1200~DVI2VGAE)<sup>*</sup>.

---

<sup>*</sup>.
<sup>Disclaimer: That is just the first link I found. I do not work for, nor do I have experience with StarTech.</sup>